# Eliminate titles from plots in order to have one main title

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, new-operator, ggpubr

im trying to use ggarrange from ggpubr to have multiple, plots in one general plot. I have my plots saved, and each one has a title, i want to eliminate those titles from each plot when the multiple plot comes, here are my plots:

```
dic_plot_int <- ordenes_dic %>%
  filter(corteesp == 1) %>%
  group_by(espesor) %>%
  summarise(MTS.4 = sum(MTS.4)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(espesor,MTS.4, fill= espesor))+     
  geom_col(width = .5)+ geom_bar(stat= "identity", colour ="black")+
  geom_text(aes(label = MTS.4), vjust = -0.2) +
  labs(title = "Indicador de Productividad de órdenes Integrales", subtitle = "Fenabel Aldama Diciembre 2023", x= "Espesor del Cristal en milímetros", y= "Metros Cuadrados", fill="Espesor")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#21BCDF","#74EA2C","#EA441B","#D051F5"),  labels =c("6mm","8mm","9.5mm", "12.7mm"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#F7D2AF', color = 'purple'))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,400))

jan_plot_int <- ordenes_ene %>%
  filter(corteesp == 1) %>%
  group_by(espesor) %>%
  summarise(MTS.4 = sum(MTS.4)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(espesor,MTS.4, fill= espesor))+     
  geom_col(width = .5)+ geom_bar(stat= "identity", colour ="black")+
  geom_text(aes(label = MTS.4), vjust = -0.2) +
  labs(title = "Indicador de Productividad de órdenes Integrales", subtitle = "Fenabel Aldama Enero 2024", x= "Espesor del Cristal en milímetros", y= "Metros Cuadrados", fill="Espesor")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#21BCDF","#EA441B","#D051F5"),  labels =c("6mm","9.5mm", "12.7mm"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#F7D2AF', color = 'purple'))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,400))
```

I dont want to eliminate from each plot the title beacuse there are some parts on my markdown where I show each plot separately, but when i want to show both plots i want to eliminate the tiles and only have one main title.

I tried using this:

```
plot <- ggarrange(dic_plot_int,jan_plot_int,ncol = 2,nrow = 1,common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right")

annotate_figure(plot, top = text_grob("Indicador de Productividad órdenes Integrales", face = "bold", size = 14))
```

But it looks really squeeze with the titles from each plot, is there any way to eliminate the titles from those plots only for the multiple plot? or somehow have something like the common.legend thing but for the title?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMabq.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! We can't test your code without sample data, but I suspect that the [`patchwork`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/index.html) library will do what you want. See https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/annotation.html for collecting titles and such.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put your plots in a `list`, then use e.g. `lapply` to remove the titles before passing the list of plots to `ggarrange` via the `plotlist=` argument.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars` let's first reproduce your issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Scatter Plot")

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = "Bar Chart")

plot <- list(p1, p2) |>
  ggarrange(plotlist = _)

annotate_figure(plot, top = text_grob("Indicador de Productividad órdenes Integrales", face = "bold", size = 14))
```

[image]

Now, using `lapply` and `labs()` we can remove the titles before passing the `list` of plots to `ggarrange`:

```r
plot <- list(p1, p2) |>
  lapply(\(x) x + labs(title = NULL)) |>
  ggarrange(plotlist = _)

annotate_figure(plot, top = text_grob("Indicador de Productividad órdenes Integrales", face = "bold", size = 14))
```

[image]

Or as already suggested by @r2evans in his comment using `patchwork` you could do:

```r
p1 + p2 &
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Indicador de Productividad órdenes Integrales",
    theme = theme_grey() + theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, hjust = .5))
  ) &
  labs(title = NULL)
```

[image]